# Understanding an undefined period of repayment in employment contract w/r/t education tuition reimbursement

Tags: contract-law, employment

I may be a position to end my employment before completing a mandatory employment period following receipt of tuition expenses. While reading through my employer's policies on the subject, I note how vague the expectations are for this situation. As the sum to be repaid would be a sizable five figures, I would not be able to provide a lump sum without a loan to cover most of the amount.

My question is: given the vague wording below, what would be the standard interpretation (if any) regarding period of repayment? Is it implied that the full sum would become immediately payable? Am I in a position to dictate terms of repayment, such as over the period of 12 months?

I accept that I should expect any exact terms to be discussed between both parties, but I'd like to understand if I am obligated to an unconditional acceptance of whatever terms are presented to me or if there is enough abstractness to grant me leverage in negotiation.

The full text of the agreement section is as follows:

> Furthermore, when Education Reimbursement is approved, processed and
>   reimbursement made to the employee, re-payment will be required should
>   the employee voluntarily terminate employment within twelve (12)
>   months of the date when the education reimbursement payment was made.
>   As a condition to being eligible to participate in this Education
>   Reimbursement program, Employee authorizes the Company, to the extent
>   permitted by applicable law, to deduct from final wages or other
>   monies due Employee any re payment amounts owed by employee to Company
>   under this section

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing vague here: the money is due and payable at the time you cease employment.